# This field can have no more than 255 characters error - multiple values

Tags: document-library, multiple-values

I have a document library. I have a list I use to store categories.
Then I have a lookup from my doc lib that uses this category column and I made it accept multiple values.
When users try to upload documents and add multiple records using the multiple values they get the error:

> This field can have no more than 255 characters.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Answer number 2 fixed this error for, how do you mark it as the answer??

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is possible by setting the "UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary" attribute to True.  I ran into the same issue recently and after setting that attribute to True, I did not get the error any more.

Comment: Hi and welcome to our site! Please don't add your name or "Thanks" as a signature to posts. It adds unnecessary information and "noise" to the page that decreases its value. Thanks :)

Comment: Chirag can you elaborate where you set the "UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary" to true?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Patrick, I don't think there is a way around this with your current design. The only possible solution I could think of would be to make your categories field "Multiple Lines of Text" but then you lose your lookup ability. Since there are so many categories that are being applied to a document, I wonder if tagging would be a good approach instead. It is built-in to SharePoint 2010, but you would unfortunately have to custom write it or purchase third-party tagging software for SharePoint 2007.